# wait() and notify() java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I hope you can help me, I have some issue with wait and notify because my application doesnt work when I do this and I don't understand why. The goal is that ApplicationMetier detect if a software is launched and if the software is not present, we can continue and make executeTravauxSelectionnes

```
public void executeTravauxSelectionnes(String entreeUtilisateur) {

        // Création d'un thread pour exécuter le logiciel métier
        // attendre que le logiciel métier soit inactif
        new Thread(() -> {
                 Optional<ProcessHandle> process = ProcessHandle.allProcesses().filter(p -> p.info().command().isPresent() && p.info().command().get().contains(propert.getProperty("softwarePath"))).findFirst();
                 if (!process.isPresent()) {
                     System.out.println("Le logiciel métier est inactif");
notify();
                 } else {
                     System.out.println("Le logiciel métier est actif");
                     try {
                         // attendre (wait)
                         wait();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
                 //thread.sleep(1000);
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
             }).start();


        // Divise l'entrée de l'utilisateur en une liste de numéros de travaux
        String[] travauxSelectionnes = entreeUtilisateur.split(",");
        int nombreDeThreads = travauxSelectionnes.length;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nombreDeThreads); // Création d'un pool de threads avec un nombre fixe de threads

        // Parcours des numéros de travaux sélectionnés
        for (String travail : travauxSelectionnes) {
            // Si le numéro est un seul travail
            if (travail.matches("\\d+")) {

                int travailNumber = Integer.parseInt(travail.trim());
                // Exécute le travail correspondant dans un thread séparé
                executor.execute(() -> executeTravail(travailNumber));
            }

            // Si le numéro est une plage de travaux
            else if (travail.matches("\\d+-\\d+")) {
                String[] range = travail.split("-");
                int start = Integer.parseInt(range[0].trim());
                int end = Integer.parseInt(range[1].trim());
                // Exécute les travaux dans la plage spécifiée dans des threads séparés
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                    int travailNumber = i;
                    executor.execute(() -> executeTravail(travailNumber));
                }
            }
            // Si le numéro de travail n'est pas valide, ignorer
            else {
                System.out.println("Numéro de travail invalide: " + travail);
            }
        }
        //création d'un thread qui met en pause le programme tant que le logiciel métier n'est pas fermé


        // Fermeture du pool de threads une fois que toutes les tâches sont soumises à l'exécution
        executor.shutdown(); // Fermeture du pool de threads une fois que toutes les tâches sont soumises à l'exécution
    }
}
```

So i made a new edit :
I observe that when I do that I have the error on line : wait(); because : current thread is not owner ; i have like an application for exemaple the calculor when it's launched, i want to pause the "executeTravauxSelectionnes"

Comment: First, wait and notifyAll have to be called on the same object.  Second, you need a Thread.sleep in your `while` loop;  constantly calling ProcessHandle.allProcesses() will hog the CPU (or at least one CPU core) needlessly.  Third, your question will get more responses if you describe the problem with more detail than just “my application doesnt work when i do this.”  What behavior were you expecting?  What did you observe instead?

Comment: There are two ways someone can use threads: you choose to implement the Runnable interface. It is not possible to call wait() while the tread itself is not started. Can you edit your question title to be more specific?

Comment: @VGR , I edit my questions ^^

Comment: If you expect readers (of your question) to understand the comments in the code, they should be in English.

Comment: “The goal is that ApplicationMetier detect if a software is launched…” I don’t understand why wait and notify are needed for this.  Or why you would need more than one Thread.

Comment: By the way, I’d guess you want [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()) rather than `findFirst`.

Comment: By the way, the `Executor#execute` method may or may *not* run in the background on another thread. You likely want `ExecutorService#submit`.

Comment: By the way, calling `shutdown` is insufficient to end an executor service. See the boilerplate code given to you in the Javadoc for `ExecutorService`. And see its `close` method.

Comment: As I read it, both your new thread and your loop through `travauxSelectionnes` execute only once. Is that your intention? Or did you wat to repeat your check-for-process-otherwise repeatedly?

Comment: @BasilBourque I want to repeat it in this loop ...

Comment: You don’t have a loop.

Answer (score 2):

> I have the error on line : `wait();` because : "current thread is not owner"

`wait()` is an `Object` method. Normally, you would write `o.wait();` when you want the caller to wait until some other thread calls `o.notify()` or `o.notifyAll()`. If you simply write `wait();` then the object that you're doing it to is the `this` object. Writing `wait();` is the same as calling `this.wait();`

The error happened because `o.wait()` is only allowed inside a `synchronized(o){...}` block. Or, if you're simply going to be calling `wait()`, then that must happen inside a `synchronized(this)` block or inside a `synchronized` method of the `this` object.

That being said, `wait()` and `notify()` and `notifyAll()` belong to a very low level mechanism for signalling between threads, and it is only ever meant to be used in a very specific way. I strongly suggest that you work through the official tutorial before you attempt to use them in your own project:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html